# Remainder through recursion

Tags: c

I am learning recursion and i encountered a conceptual doubt while solving the problem of calculation of remainder when a positive integer is a is divided by a positive integer b.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int x;
int rem(int a,int b)
{
    x=a;
    if(x>=b)
    {
        x=x-b;
        rem(x,b);
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter a & b\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    int y =rem(a,b);
    printf("rem is :%d",y);
    return 0;
}
```

Its working fine. I have learned that for every call a new set of formal parameters and local variables are created.

So i experimented it by printing x on return of every recursive call!
But it is printing 1 1 1 1. Why is the value of x corresponding to a particular call not printed. ?

Why only the last modified value printed?.. Is that because i declared 'x' as global?

Comment: "Why only the last modified value printed?.. Is that because i declared 'x' as global?" Yes. Think about what is happening step by step.

Comment: global value has same copy for different all, local variable are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case perhaps you need only to move your print up

```
int rem(int a,int b)
{
    x=a;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    if(x>=b)
    {
        x=x-b;
        rem(x,b);
    }
    return x;
}
```

But I think you should avoid the use of global variables in a recursive alrotithm. It could make the algorithm very difficult to reason about. Recursive functions are better to be 'pure functions'.

Answer (score 2):

It is because while `x >= b`, `rem()` is repeatedly called before `printf()s` are called. Only after `x < b` will the `printf()s` are called as each call on `rem()` unwinds.

You might want to make `x` local to `rem()` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring issues with checking the return value from `scanf()` and that the two entered values are both positive, etc, I think you can and should avoid `x` altogether.  You could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int rem(int a, int b)
{
    if (a >= b)
        a = rem(a-b, b);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter a & b\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    int y = rem(a, b);
    printf("rem(%d, %d) is: %d\n", a, b, y);
    return 0;
}
```

This code captures the return value from `rem()` at each level of recursion.  In this case, because the returned value doesn't change as the recursion unwinds, you could use the global variable `x`, but there is no need for it, and you should avoid global variables whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int fun(int,int);

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    fun(a,b);
    //printf("%d",fun(a,b));

}
int fun(int a,int b)
{

 
   if(a<b)
   printf("%d",a);
   if(a>=b)
   a=fun(a-b,b);
   return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO!  Good answers will often contain an explanation of *why* as well as code snippets.  Your answer would likely get more recognition with a more complete explanation.